# local variable X referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, reference, jira

I have tried to use the below function to connect to jira and except authentication error 401:

```
def jira_connect(User, Passwd):
try:
    jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(User, Passwd), options={'server': 'https://jira-server-address'})
except JIRAError as e:
    if e.status_code == 401:
        print "Login to JIRA failed. Please check your username and password and try again !"
        exit()
return jira

def main(Thisuser, Thispasswd):
User = Thisuser
Passwd = Thispasswd
jira = jira_connect(User, Passwd)
if __name__== "__main__":
Getuser = getpass.getuser()
Getpasswd = getpass.getpass()
main(Getuser, Getpasswd)
```

But after that i got:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'jira' referenced before assignment
Is that because i should also give value to jira variable under except JIRAError ? Because if i move try and except jut put as blow, it works fine:

```
def jira_connect(User, Passwd):
    jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(User, Passwd), options={'server': 'https://jira-server-address'})
    return jira
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by including the return in the try block:

```py
def jira_connect(User, Passwd):
    try:
        jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(User, Passwd), options={'server': 'https://jira-server-address'})
        return jira
    except JIRAError as e:
        if e.status_code == 401:
            print "Login to JIRA failed. Please check your username and password and try again !"
            exit()
```

Otherwise if an exception is encountered, the local var `jira` is not assigned at the point of return.

Otherwise you could assign, for instance, `jira = None` in the except block:

```py
def jira_connect(User, Passwd):
    try:
        jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(User, Passwd), options={'server': 'https://jira-server-address'})
    except JIRAError as e:
        if e.status_code == 401:
            print "Login to JIRA failed. Please check your username and password and try again !"
            exit()
        jira = None
    return jira
```

But I'd be wary of this in case a `JIRAError` with an status code different from 401 resulted in a `None` return, and code later on in the script relied on a valid connection. Depending on this, you may want to put the `exit()` call in the except block outside of the if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i tried both but still get the error below: WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET https://jira-server.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 9.50354793356s. Err: 401 Unauthorized, i think this has something to do with the jira itself cause i could not get status_code 401 after this warnning.

Comment: Yup— looks like the unbound local error is resolved. It looks like Jira is handling the auth issue internally, giving a warning and retrying after a timeout rather than throwing the exception you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer !